# В тело письма mailto вставить в body результат JS скрипта

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Добрый день, есть поле html , как в тело письма вставить результат JS скрипта?

```html
<a href="mailto:imst@mail.ru?subject=130000027&body="в тело вставить результат скрипта JS (возвращает строку)" </a>
```

Comment: результат скрипта строка?

Comment: @Horchynskyi да

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById("abc").href="mailto:mail@mail.ru?subject=130000027&body=1";
```

```html
<a href="#" id="abc">Mail me</a>
```

Или так:

```js
var temp = document.getElementById("abc").href;
var result ="result"; //Это переменная которую вы хотите вставить в конец после выполнения вашего скрипта
    document.getElementById("abc").href=temp+result;
```

```html
<a href="mailto:mail@mail.ru?subject=130000027&body=" id="abc">Mail me 2</a>
```

Comment: Мне нужно вызвать скрипт JS ? без php не обойтись ?

Comment: @VadimPopov Вы вместо xyz.php форматируете свою строку

Comment: я дописал пример

Comment: @PauloBerezini можно ли как то выполнить скрипт для всех элементов входящих в один div например или как то ещё ?

Comment: @VadimPopov это пример надо видеть что конкретно надо изменять( советую создать новый вопрос в таком случае)

Comment: @PauloBerezini Спасибо всё получилось :)

Comment: @VadimPopov, всегда пожалуйста =)